# Getting an error "The authentication or decryption has failed." in monodevelop on ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, mono, ssl-certificate, monodevelop

I am trying to run a project using monodevelop over SSL. I have used the correct SSL certificates for this and it works perfectly on Firefox. However, when I try to run the project in Chrome or Chromium browser, it gives an exception given below.

```
System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: Error while sending TLS Alert (Fatal:HandshakeFailiure): Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The client stopped the handshake.
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslServerStream.EndNegotiateHandshake (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x000b9] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0000c] in <filename unknown>:0  ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: The socket has been shut down. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The socket has been shut down
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndSend (IAsyncResult result) [0x00033] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndWrite (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0005f] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndWrite (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x000af] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndSendRecord (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00040] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.SendRecord (ContentType contentType, System.Byte[] recordData) [0x0000b] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.SendAlert (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Alert alert) [0x00027] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.SendAlert (System.Exception& ex) [0x00021] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.EndRead (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00057] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Net.Security.Private.LegacySslStream.EndAuthenticateAsServer (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00011] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Net.Security.Private.LegacySslStream.AuthenticateAsServer (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate serverCertificate, Boolean clientCertificateRequired, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) [0x0000e] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.HttpConnection.Init () [0x0001d] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.HttpConnection..ctor (System.Net.Sockets.Socket sock, System.Net.EndPointListener epl, Boolean secure, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate cert) [0x00096] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.EndPointListener.OnAccept (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x0008e] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompleted (System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs e) [0x00014] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.Complete () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<AcceptAsyncCallback>m__0 (IAsyncResult ares) [0x000a0] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncResult+<Complete>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 (System.Object _) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem () [0x00019] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () [0x00096] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: Why not try breaking out WireShark and seeing who's rejecting the connection?

Also, what version of mono are you running? Is it possible that the server is rejecting the connection because the client does not support the required protocol by the server?

Comment: I am using mono develop 5.10

Comment: Yes that's the version of mono develop, but what version of the mono framework are you using? try running mono --version to see. Current version is 4.6 I believe.

Comment: It is Mono JIT compiler version 4.4.2

Comment: I have upgraded it 4.8.0 but but the issue still persist.